# "No such column" when checking for table column

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a table to add data to a database but I am not sure where to create the column for 'emails'. My final aim for this is to be able to enter a username (email) and password and for it to be saved into a database but I am not sure how to do this. Here is my code currently:

```
import sqlite3

def save_to_database(my_stack, filename = 'stack_database.db'):

    conn = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    c = conn.cursor()

    for row in c.execute('SELECT email FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table"'):
        if row != None:
            c.execute("DROP TABLE emails")

    c.execute("CREATE TABLE emails(email text,login_date text)")
    ...
```

Comment: This is really hard to read; the indentation is messed up in the first block of code. Could you please a) reduce the code down to only that which you think is relevant (all the `print` statements are not) and b) include a stack trace so that we can actually see what line causes the error? In other words, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlite_master` table does not have a column named `email`; the entire table structure is contained in the text in the `sql` column.

You could check for the table name itself (but note that if no row is found, no row is returned, not even an empty one, so it does not make sense to try to handle this with a `for` loop):

```
c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'emails'")
if not c.fetchall():
    c.execute('DROP TABLE emails')
```

However, there is an easier method to ensure that a table is removed, regardless of its previous state:

```
c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS emails')
```